# Creation of distribution from existing system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso, distributions

I have a task of creating similarly configured systems for my office. 
I have an Ubuntu system that I have configured; for example:

- I have `ssh` service running.
- I have changed the configuration file to not permit root login remotely.

and other such kind of settings have been applied for many other programs.

Is there a way by which I can create an ISO from my current Ubuntu system with these settings intact and distribute it for installation in the office? I read about a program called Distroshare, which can create a live system –
but how can I create an installer? Is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do an [OEM-Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), then make an image of that installation with [clonezilla](https://www.clonezilla.org) or a similar tool and then deploy that image.

I have used this approach succesfully myself for handful of machines.

For larger deployments, you will want to setup a PXE-Server that holds the installation image and boot the machines from the network.  You probably want to make use of "[preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs02.html)" in this scenario.

You may want to setup some sort of config-management as well, because you will certainly need to change things after the initial installation.

E.g. add a user "ansible" during the OEM-Install, along with a public key in .ssh/authorized_keys, so you can use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com) to manage the desktops later.
But that is just one of a dozen or so solutions...

Comment: But can this image created by clonezilla be made installable??Like I don't want a live Ubuntu but an Ubuntu that can be installed on the hard disk of the systems in my office.If it is possible could you tell me how to do this??

Comment: The details are described in the linked documents.  There is no need to make the image installable.  The image is just written to a new disk with clonezilla and after that you can boot from that disk.